# Does Android Data Binding replaces findViewById?

Tags: android, data-binding

I saw some articles when Data Binding was announced have titles like this "Time To Leave findViewById", for some reason I thought it's going to be a replacement for libs like [butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) but when I looked at it and it seemed to me that it's only links model classes to view (title -> R.id.title) so when change title in view or in code it will reflect on the other end.

Is that all to it or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is one aspect, but it isn't the biggest. You can add expressions to do XML and have the data assigned directly to the View. For example, if you have a TextView showing the first name, you might have an expression like:

```
<TextView android:text="@{user.firstName}" .../>
```

This helps eliminate the boilerplate code linking data to the UI. It is another reason not to need `findViewById`.

Another convenience is that you can assign event listeners to your views in the XML. It appears similar to android:onClick, though it doesn't have the performance overhead of reflection.

There are other conveniences, but the major one is the data linking to the UI.